# Use Java 8 Stream with ObjectMapper readValue method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've created a method that iterates over the String list and converts it to a POJO list using ObjectMapper readValue method.

```
public static <T> List<T> mapPayloadListToPOJOList(List<String> payloadList, Class<T> pojo) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<T> pojoList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String payload : payloadList) {
        T mapped = mapper.readValue(payload, pojo);
        pojoList.add(mapped);
    }
    return pojoList;
}
```

1. Is there a way I could use Java 8 stream instead of this implementation?
2. Could you provide me a solution?

I was trying to use map but it doesn't allow to apply the `Class<T>` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done very easily by removing the for loop and replace it with the stream, but lambda expressions face some problem in handling checked exceptions.

You can resolve it using the separate method for conversion and handle the exception in that method (either by logging it or rethrowing it as an unchecked exception).

```
    public static <T> List<T> mapPayloadListToPOJOList(List<String> payloadList, Class<T> pojo) {
        return payloadList.stream()
                          .map(string -> convert(string, pojo))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static <T> T convert(String string, Class<T> pojo) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(string, pojo);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is what I was missing, returning the null value.

Comment: This way of “handling” the exception, will hurt you some day…

Comment: Holger I know, this not an ideal way to handle exceptions. I have written it this way, only to explain the stream processing.

Comment: It’s clear that this is just an example, but using, e.g. `throw new UncheckedIOException(e);` is not more complicated than `e.printStackTrace();`, especially when considering that you can omit the `return null;` statement…

Comment: Yes, I got your point and I also throw exceptions back by wrapping them into some custom unchecked exception and that is why I have already mentioned it " handle the exception in that method (either by logging it or rethrowing it as an unchecked exception)". Anyway Thanks, And I am updating the answer to throw it instead of priting it.

Answer (score 2):

Thought it should have been `map` rather than `forEach` ..

```
payloadList.stream()
    .map(s -> mapper.readValue(s, pojo))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The difference is, `map` maps each element from the original `List` to a new element using the lambda provided (`s -> mapper.readValue(s, pojo)`), whereas `forEach` performs a [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) for each element in the original `List` without returning anything.

From [Java 8 stream tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check this [link](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/), you can convert the list into a stream and then map each value with something like

```
payloadList.stream()
    .forEach( s -> mapper.readValue(s,pojo))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```